# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - Works with string but not parameter

Tags: split, parameters

I'm currently trying to make some fancy staggered text appear on my website. It works just fine if I simply set the str variable to some string in the function, but if I set it to a parameter, even if I call the staggeredText() function with an argument, like so: `staggeredText(test)` and receive it with the `text` parameter in the function, it gives me an error that reads `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.`

What am I doing wrong? I've only been doing Javascript for a couple of months, so I wouldn't understand super complex answers. For some reason it cannot split str if it's set to a parameter, even if that parameter is a string.

Edit: It also works if I simply set str to a variable outside the function, but somehow it doesn't work if I pass it through as a parameter, which is vital if I want to use this function for a lot of different text.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

<script>
    let app = document.getElementById('app');
    let i = 0;
    let str = '';
    let strArray ='';
    let result = '';
    let test = "This is a test";

    view();
    function view() {
        html = result;

        app.innerHTML = html;
    }

    function staggeredText(text) {

        str = text;

        strArray = str.split("");

        setTimeout(()=>{
            if (i < strArray.length) {
            result += strArray[i];
            view();
            i++;
            staggeredText();
            }

            else i = 0;
        },100);


    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: staggeredText is never called in your example.

Comment: Yeah, I call it with console because I'm testing out how to make it work. I type `staggeredText(test)` into the console.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the function is recursive and you have this line: `staggeredText();`  but that calls it with no parameter so the variable text is undefined during the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Ah woops I figured it out, I don't use the parameter as an argument while calling it inside the function. Fixed now :D